# OpenCV. Image returned as a grayscale instead of RGB

Tags: ios, opencv, uiimage

I am doing some experiments with OpenCV on iOS. I try to put a png image on top of a detected face.Thats the image I try to place upon a deteted face:[image]

But I get this.:[image]

I use this function to convert a UIImage to a cvMat.:

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to    data
                                                cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                8,                          // Bits per component
                                                cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return cvMat;
}
```

Here I add the image.:

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;
{
 cv::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
 cv::Mat frame_gray;

cvtColor(image, frame_gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,   cv::Size(100, 100));

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
{
    rectangle(image, cv::Point(faces[i].x, faces[i].y),
              cv::Point(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height),
              cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
    CGPoint pos;
    pos.x = faces[i].x;
    pos.y = faces[i].y;

    cv::Rect roi( cv::Point( pos.x , pos.y ), cv::Size( faces[i].width , faces[i].height   ));
    cv::Mat destinationROI = image( roi );
    cv::Mat smallImage = [self faceIntoImageView:pos size:CGSizeMake(faces[i].width,   faces[i].height)];
    smallImage.copyTo(image(roi));

 }
 }

-(cv::Mat)faceIntoImageView:(CGPoint)position size:(CGSize)size
{

UIImage* face = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Face1.png"];
face = [self imageWithImage:face scaledToSize:size];
return [self cvMatFromUIImage:face];
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Why is the Output Image tottally different from the original. The Output Image seems to be grey..

Comment: Can you paste method 'imageWithImage:face scaledToSize:' also?

Comment: faceIntoImageView for this method , which class is imported???, i am using CvVideoCameraDelegate instead of PhotoCameraDelegate...??

Answer (score 3):

You should swap B and R channels.

```
    - (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to    data
                                                    cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

//-------swap channels
std::vector<Mat> ch;
cv::split(cvMat,ch);
std::swap(ch[0],ch[2]);
cv::merge(ch,cvMat);
//-------
    return cvMat;
    }
```

Comment: I understand this question as "Why overlayed face is not natural color?". (The image not gray by the way.) The answer is "Because red and blue channels swapped.". To correct this autor of question should swap channels back.

Comment: Thanks a lot with help of cvtColor( cvMat, cvMat, CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB ); I could swap r and b. But now the alpha channel is lost and the image show black where a "alpha color" should be

Comment: I think the best way is split image by channels (using cv::split), and then combine them in order you need (use cv::merge).

Comment: Hey Andrey, 

as you can see I posted a method to convert a UIImage to a cvMat, how exactly can I use cv::split and cv::merge in this method?

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Not sure about iOS (have no expiriance in iOS programming), but in PC it must work.

Comment: Thank you, but the result is on iOS the same, instead of an alpha background the background is black. I think the channel gets lost when converting from uiimage to cvmat. I have to look at this in more detail

Comment: You can easy check it. Just copy alpha channel to all layers, and you will be able to see it. By the way, there is copyTo method in Mat class that uses mask for copy operation.